# cakephp 3 model is not associated error

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

Tabel `coding`

```
id |  level1  |  level2  |  title
_____________________________________
1  |  100     |  1       |  numberOne
2  |  100     |  2       |  NumberTwo
3  |  101     |  1       |  Compay
4  |  101     |  2       |  association
```

Table `Organizations`

```
id  | name  |  type  | level
____________________________
1   | intel |  3     |  1 
2   | IBM   |  4     |  2
```

Model `Organizations`

```
class organizationsTable extends table
{    
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {       
        $this->table('organizations');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

            $this->belongsTo('yyyy', [
                 'foreignKey' => 'type',
                 'className' => 'coding'    
                 ],
                 'xxxx', [
                 'foreignKey' => 'level',
                 'className' => 'coding'
           ]);

    }
}
```

Controller

```
$organization->find('all')->contain(['yyyy'])->contain(['xxxx'])->toList()  ;
```

i write this but say error :`organizations is not associated with xxxx`

how can do Multiple relations to the same model in cakephp3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in cakephp2 [Multiple relations to the same model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model)

but in cakephp3 try like this

Model

```
$this->belongsTo('aliasName1', [
    'foreignKey' => 'type',
    'className' => 'coding'
    ]);
$this->belongsTo('aliasName2', [
    'foreignKey' => 'level',
    'className' => 'coding' 
    ]);
```

Controller

```
$organization->find('all')->contain(['aliasName1'])->contain(['aliasName2']);
```